# Insert multiple rows but not empty fields

Tags: php, mysqli

I have 4 rows that need to be inserted into db IF THEY ARE NOT EMPTY.
But I can't make it work.

this x 4 times

```
<select class="form-control" id="masura" name="masura[]">
<option value='' > -- </option>
<option value='XS' > XS </option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="stoc" name="stoc[]" >
```

and this php

```
$row_data = array();
foreach($_POST['stoc'] as $row=>$stoc) {
    $stoc=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$stoc);
    $masura=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,($_POST['masura'][$row]));
    $row_data[] = "('$masura', '$stoc' , '$dirName')";
}

if (!empty($row_data)) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO stoc (masura, stoc, prodid) VALUES '.implode

    (',', $row_data);
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
}
```

the issue is that it will also insert empty fields (if I enter only 1 field, it will insert that field with other 3 ones empty)

Thanks

Comment: `$row_data` will never be empty. You need to check if `$stoc` and `$_POST['masura'][$row]` are empty before put them in `$row_data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add empty fields to `$row_data`:

```
foreach($_POST['stoc'] as $row=>$stoc) {
    if (empty($stoc) || empty($_POST['masura'][$row])) {
        // Skip if either field is empty
        continue;
    }
    $stoc=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$stoc);
    $masura=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,($_POST['masura'][$row]));
    $row_data[] = "('$masura', '$stoc' , '$dirName')";
}
```

Comment: something is not right because I get blank screen (syntax error, unexpected '{') at second row

Comment: Sorry, left out a parenthesis.

Comment: Happens all the time when I edit here, since the SO editor doesn't do parenthesis balancing. If you're not using an IDE that highlights problems like this, you should.